# Make this radiobutton look better

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

Hi guys I'm making this form with some radio buttons and bootstrap but the radiobuttons I don't like the way they look:

[radio buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6nwb.png)

and this is my html code:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Memoria SD:
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="memorias" name="memoria" value="si">SI
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" id="memorian" name="memoria" value="no" checked="true">NO
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>SIM Card:
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="chips" name="chip" value="si">SI
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" id="chipn" name="chip" value="no" checked="true">NO
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Tapa:
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="tapas" name="tapa" value="si" checked="true">SI
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" id="tapan" name="tapa" value="no">NO
  </label>
</div>
```

I want all the radio buttons aligned this way
(x)SI ()NO
(x)SI ()NO
(x)SI ()NO

not the way it is at the moment:
(x)SI       ()NO
(x)SI    ()NO
(x)SI ()NO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your `<label>` are wrapped around your group titles. `<label>` is meant for individual inputs.

Try this instead:

```
<div class="form-group">
    Memoria SD:<br>
    <input type="radio" id="memorias" name="memoria" value="si">SI
    <input type="radio" id="memorian" name="memoria" value="no" checked="true">NO
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    SIM Card:<br>
    <input type="radio" id="chips" name="chip" value="si">SI
    <input type="radio" id="chipn" name="chip" value="no" checked="true">NO
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    Tapa:<br>
    <input type="radio" id="tapas" name="tapa" value="si" checked="true">SI
    <input type="radio" id="tapan" name="tapa" value="no">NO
</div>
```